# Android to change APP theme dynamically

Tags: android, colors, styles, themes, color-scheme

I would like to know if we can change the theme of an app dynamically. The color codes for the theme will come dynamically from an API. Therefore I need to change the app theme as per the color codes from an API. Can anyone please tell whether it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can change between themes dynamically, but you cannot change a theme itself. Themes are immutable. You can create themes in the styles.xml and change the theme of the app by calling the method

```
setTheme(android.R.style.YOUR_CUSTOM_THEME);
```

But the colors you get from your api dynamically cannot be set to your theme.